# Inject SVG element and access it using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am creating svg element (a point)  dynamically inside of graphic-content class and the trying to access the point element using jquery but its not working. Any sol.?

```
 /* code for creating svg element */
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 0,
    $y1 = 0;
    $con = $(".graphic-content");

    var $svg = $(svg("svg")).attr({
     "width": "946", "height": "280"
     }).appendTo($con);

   /* create a point */
      $(function() {
         $(svg("circle")).attr({
         "cx": x, "cy": $y1,"r":"3","class":"point"
          }).appendTo($svg);
  });
   /* hover effect*/
 $("circle").hover(function(){
   $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
   alert("Hello!");
 });
});
function svg(elem) {
       return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", elem);
    }
```

Comment: Where are `x` and `$y1` defined?

Comment: sorry to mention! x and $y1 are coordinates of circle element which i have declared in my source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` and `$y1` do not appear to be defined? Try using `mouseenter`, `mouseleave` events attached to `svg`, event delegation. Removing `alert()` call; setting `cursor:point` using `.toggleClass()`

```js
/* code for creating svg element */
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var x = 0,
     $y1 = 0;
   $con = $(".graphic-content");

   var $svg = $(svg("svg")).attr({
     "width": "946",
     "height": "280"
   }).appendTo($con);

   /* create a point */
   $(function() {
     $(svg("circle")).attr({
       "cx": x,
       "cy": $y1,
       "r": "3",
       "class": "point"
     }).appendTo($svg);
   });
   /* hover effect*/
   $("svg").on("mouseenter", "circle", function(e) {
     console.log(e);
     $("body").toggleClass("hovered");
     // alert("Hello!");
   }).on("mouseleave", "circle", function(e) {
     console.log(e);
     $("body").toggleClass("hovered")
   })
 });

 function svg(elem) {
   return document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", elem);
 }
```

```css
.hovered {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="graphic-content"></div>
```

Comment: and what is the problem with directly accessing to circle element as i have used?

Comment: i replaced my hover action code with yours but still hover effect function is not working.

Comment: Have you tried stacksnippets? `cursor` is set to `pointer` here when mouse enters `svg circle`. See also `console`

Comment: yeah i already did that, i also tried to get some response as console.log("Hello!) again here but not worked.

Comment: _"yeah i already did that, i also tried to get some response as console.log("Hello!) again here but not worked"_ Can you create a jsfiddle to demonstrate? https://jsfiddle.net/xu7heww1/

Comment: a saw your code on https://jsfiddle.net/xu7heww1/ its working here but i its not working on my own device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109330/discussion-between-avipatel-and-guest271314).